# SQL delete statement with small set of rows to delete takes very long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-delete

I have a very basic delete statement that takes an incredible long time to execute

The code is as below

```
select PTRXID
  into __tmpPTRXID
  from PermitsTracked_Requirements_XREF
  where 
    PermitID = @permitID
    and (
        IsAction = 0 
        and (
            IsCompleted = 0
            or IsDenied = 0
        )
    )
--....
;Disable Trigger <...>
-- all triggers disabled

delete from PermitsTracked_Requirements_XREF 
  where 
    PermitID = @permitID
    and PTRXID in (select ptrxid from __tmpPTRXID)
;Enable Trigger <...>
```

There are at most a few hundred records to delete at a time, but usually only tens.
But this doesn't make any difference.
The table is indeed very large, tens of millions of records.
But I have other similar tables in the db with similar deletes and all just work almost instantly.

I checked the table and it has no cascade delete relations.
It actually had initially, but I perform deletes on the related tables first, and eventually I removed all the cascade deletes, to no avail.

I disabled all the triggers just to be sure they don't impact speed.
The select on the same set is run instantly.

There are several indexes on the table (about 10) but not with any calculation.

I created a specific index to address this case as below, but it doesn't help

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_PermitID_PTRXID] ON [dbo]. 
[PermitsTracked_Requirements_XREF]
(
  [PermitID] ASC,
  [PTRXID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [Primary]
```

Any idea what can be, where to look for?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? Where is the most time being spent? Why do you need a temp table, why not just apply the predicate in the delete directly? Also please include the table schema definition and indexes.

Comment: Thanks, Stu, this helped me solve the issue. There was another related table which didn't had index on the related column. Once I added that it worked instantly, as it should. Thank you.

Comment: @Stu, I had to use a temp table because I had to delete previously from other related tables to disable cascade delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stu suggested, when I checked the query plan (which to my shame I omitted initially) I discovered another related table which didn't had index on the related column.

After added it the delete worked instantly, as expected

Comment: Would be helpful to others if you added the plan to the question (you can share it via https://PasteThePlan.com) and also include all relevant tables and index definitions

Comment: Unfortunately that's difficult - the query plan is very large because that was a master table, with about two dozen related tables set with RI rules for cascade delete. One of the related tables (which I wasn't aware of at first) didn't had index on the foreign key column, and with 10M+ records in it, it was the query killer.